# Input value still a string after parsing to float

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know where am I failing. I am trying a simple thing: retrieve an input, parse it to float and do a calculation with that value (introduced by the user), but yet, it returns NaN.

Here it is the input (I make a string replace of commas to dots in my code, but right now I am just trying the simplest way in the Firebug console):

```
<input id="percent_31" class="form-control input-sm text-right" type="text" name="percent[31]" value="-3.3333">
```

This is what I am trying:

```
var percent = parseFloat($('#percent_31').val()).toFixed(2);
console.log(percent);
console.log(jQuery.type(percent));
/*This returns -3.33 and string type*/
console.log((100 + percent)/100); 
/*This, as expected, returns NaN*/
```

This, on the other hand, works.

```
percent = -3.33;
console.log(percent);
console.log(jQuery.type(percent));
/*This returns -3.33 and number type*/

console.log((100 + percent)/100);
/*This returns what I need: 0.9667*/
```

Comment: `toFixed` returns string, you can't crop your float this way.

Comment: [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) turns a number into a string by design.

Comment: As Maxx says `.toFixed(2);` returns a string - because `5.00` *technically* isn't a number, it's just `5` - so it needs to become a string to maintain formatting

Comment: The above comments explain why you're getting what you're getting. An easy fix is to just stick a `+` in front of your parseFloat: `var percent = +parseFloat($('#percent_31').val()).toFixed(2);` and voila, a number not a string.

Comment: @j08691 This works!! Is there another way of cropping the float? The "not so easy" fix? If you add this as an answer I'll approve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **round** up to two decimals:

```
> percent = "-3.33678";
'-3.33678'
> typeof(percent);
'string'
> percent = Number(parseFloat(percent).toFixed(2));
-3.34
> typeof(percent);
'number'
```

If you want to **truncate** the decimals and not round them:

```
> percent = "-3.33678";
'-3.33678'
> typeof(percent);
'string'
> percent = Number(percent.slice(0, (percent.indexOf(".")) + 3));
-3.33
> typeof(percent);
'number'
```

Comment: This returns all decimals, I only need two.

Comment: Keep the variable as a Number to perform all your operations and don't loose precission, and use the .toFixed(2) whenever you want to print its value with only two decimals.

Comment: But I need to do the calculations with a precision of two decimals.

Comment: Then convert the variable to Number after cropping it with .toFixed(2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use '[Number()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp)'

```js
var values = $('#percent_31').val();
var percent = Number(parseFloat(values).toFixed(2));
console.log(percent);
//console.log(jQuery.type(percent));
/*This returns -3.33 and string type*/
console.log((100 + percent)/100); 
/*This, as expected, returns NaN*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="percent_31" class="form-control input-sm text-right" type="text" name="percent[31]" value="-3.3333">
```

Answer (score 0):

create a variable and assign value to that variable.

```
var myvalue = $('#percent_31').val();
var percent = parseFloat(myvalue).toFixed(2);
console.log(percent);
```

Comment: Try to use parseInt @Ika or remove tofixed

Comment: parseInt does not keep decimals.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery method [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is returning an string, so you can use [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to work with the numerical value:

```js
var val = $('#percent_31').val(),
    percent = Number(parseFloat(val).toFixed(2)),
    result = (100 + percent) / 100;

console.log('percent:', percent);
console.log('type:', $.type(percent));
console.log('result:', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="percent_31" class="form-control input-sm text-right" type="text" name="percent[31]" value="-3.3333">
```